# DJANGO count number of records with raw MYSQL query and use result in html template

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to get the total number of records of my database using raw Mysql query and render it in a html template with something like `{{ number_of_rec }}`

So far I have tried :

view.py

```
def number_of_rec(request):

    locate = Record.objects.raw("SELECT count(*) FROM mydb ")
    number_of_rec = len(locate.fetchall)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec})
```

But it's not working as `{{ number_of_rec }}` in the template html return nothing.

I also tried `number_of_rec = len(locate.fetchall)[0]` but no changes.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a raw query, why not the ORM?

Comment: Yes, it’s because my django app is somehow interfacing with a desktop app in full python / mysql. I’m used to « normal » MYSQL queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use [**`.raw(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#raw) like that. `.raw(…)` expects that that it is a query that returns columns as the model expects. But here your query will return one row and one column.

You can work with a raw query with:

```
from django.db import connection


def number_of_rec(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM mydb')
        number_of_rec = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec})
```

but using raw queries in general is often not a good idea. If you want to count the number of `Record`s, you use:

```
def number_of_rec(request):
    number_of_rec = Record.objects.count()
    render(request, 'test.html', {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec})
```

but since you don't trigger the template through that view, the logic will never render.

We can define a [*context processor* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) with:

```
# app_name/context_processors.py

from django.conf import settings


def number_of_rec(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM mydb')
        number_of_rec = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec}
```

and register the context processor with:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …,
        'context_processors': ['app_name.context_processors.number_of_rec']
    },
]
```

Comment: Ok I understand the theory. But Even with trying yours 2 exemples I'm still not able to get the number back in my template. When i put {{number_of_rec}} in a span or in the body of the html page it returns nothing ...

Comment: @Nico44044: what if you `print(number_of_rec)` in the view (before the `render` step)?

Comment: @Nico44044: I have the impression that the view is never triggered, because it normally should error with the view you demonstrated. What is the `path` that triggers the view?

Comment: this is my path in url.py : path('number_of_rec/', views.number_of_rec,name='number_of_rec'),  and I imported all from views.py with : from . import views

Comment: @Nico44044: so in your browser you go to `/number_of_rec/`?

Comment: No because I would like to be able to get the result in a simple html label in page test.html without visible redirection in browser ...

Comment: @Nico44044: well then you don't trigger the view at all, hence regardless what query (or other logic) you write, it will simply never be triggered.

Comment: Ok I understand. Is there a way to trigger the view just to get the result without a visible  redirection in browser ?

Comment: @Nico44044: wrap it in a context processor.

Comment: In the view I assume ? Could you update your answer with an exemple and integrate the context processor ?  And how to call it back in the template ? Sorry I'm familiar with Python but kind of new with the Django framework.

Comment: @Nico44044: no, a context processor is a piece of code you run each time you render the template, so you likely have a view you trigger to render `test.html`, but not the one with the `number_of_rec`, but the other one where you visit the page. Then you count the items there. Given there is such view, but somehow you view `test.html` I suppose?

Comment: @Nico44044: in fact this has not much to do with Django itself, but more how a HTTP request works: you send a request, the path determines what view is triggered and hence what logic is done, and it answers with a response. So as long as you don't visit `/number_of_rec/`, the logic is not triggered if it is a view.

Comment: Ok so should I do something like this in Urls.py :  path('test/', views.number_of_rec,name='number_of_rec'),
    path('test/', views.test,name='test'),  That would mean I trigger 2 views when calling test.html ... Is that doable ?

Comment: @Nico44044: you *can't* trigger two views, how would you "merge" the two responses. Edited with the context processor approach.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it. I did test to trigger 2 views when launching test.html and It works, it gives me the number of Record of the DB. I'm stopping here and will make a new questions if I'm struggling with pocessor approach. Many Many thanks for your help and time. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Nico44044: it will always trigger *one* view (you can validate this by inserting a `print`). Which one depends on the order of the paths.