# Django Ajax to trigger a view not working

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to trigger a view by clicking a html button in a template.

template (test.html)

```
<div id="test_count"></div>
<input type="button" value="Get number of records in DB" onclick="numberec()" />

<script>
function numberec() {
             $.ajaxSetup(
                 {data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                 });
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "../number_of_rec/",
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#test_count").html({{number_of_rec}});
                 }
             })
         }

    </script>
```

View.py

```
    def number_of_rec(request):
        number_of_rec = Record.objects.count()
        data2 = render(request, 'test.html', {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec})
        return (data2)

    def test(request):
        return render(request, 'test.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('number_of_rec/', views.number_of_rec, name='number_of_rec'),
    path('test/', views.test,name='test'),

]
```

When I go to `https://my_web_app.com/test` in the web browser, the button doesn't trigger the `number_of_rec` view and the div is not filled with the result.

BUT if I trigger the view by going to `https://my_web_app.com/number_of_rec` in web browser, the button is working and fill the div with the expected result.

What should I do for my Ajax to trigger the `number_of_rec`  view from the `test.html` page or any other page ?

I'm a bit lost ...

Thanks

Comment: I finally used this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032864/django-count-number-of-records-with-raw-mysql-query-and-use-result-in-html-templ

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the issue is related to how you are specifying the URL on your JavaScript code and the way it's being interpreted in different contexts. To make certain that your AJAX request triggers the number_of_rec view, you should specify the URL in a manner that works continuously.

```
<script>
function numberec() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'number_of_rec' %}",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#test_count").html(data.number_of_rec);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, tried your answer and still not working when I'm on the test.html page